# Power automate concurrency limit of 50 on apply to each loop

Tags: power-automate

How can I post an adaptive card and wait for a response to 3000 users or more concurrently? The apply to each loop has a limitation of 50?

I have tried limiting pagination from getting the user list and timeouts on waiting for a response.
Timeouts do not work for my use case as we want to send out the adaptive card to the userbase at once. I am expecting to send out the adaptive card to 3000 users at once and retrieve their responses

Answer (score 0):

Using a parent and child flow resolved this issue.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLhwnZ5JRvE&t=999s